# Como instalar Jquery no Angular?

Tags: jquery, angular

Qual a forma correta de instalar o jquery num projeto angular 2<sup>+</sup>?

Com bootstrap:

`npm install --save jquery@latest`

Só que ele não está disponível no node_modules para eu pegar o caminho e colocar no `angular.json`

Comment: Dá uma click dentro do meu demo, adicionei um `window.click` lá que aparece um `alert`

Comment: Esqueci de deletar essa pergunta... tinha instalado sim, só a vscode que demorou a atualizar. só fechei tudo e dei ng serve que tava ok...

Comment: Pergunta muito útil, vale a pena deixar!

Comment: Só pra avisar que o angular-cli.json agora se chama apenas angular.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### jQuery no Angular CLI

Instale o pacote através:

- `npm install jquery — save`

posteriormente em seu ./angular-cli.json.

- `“scripts”: [ “../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js” ]`,

vc tambem pode fazer o mesmo com o bootstrap como exemplo :

- “scripts”: [“../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js”]

por fim inclua em seu componente:

- `import * as $ from ‘jquery’;`

### Obs:. $ servirá para vc como referencia global do Jquery

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Look jQuery Animation working in action!';

  public ngOnInit()
  {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var div = $("div");  
        div.animate({left: '100px'}, "slow");
        div.animate({fontSize: '5em'}, "slow");
    });
});
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente desda maneira:

***npm install jquery --save***

Answer (score 2):

**Raiz do projeto:**

```
npm install jquery --save
```

**angular-cli.json**

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  ]
```

**Ts:**

```
   import $ from "jquery";
```

## [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cotaov)